# Pass a prop from state and do not trigger update in connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am currently grabbing a prop from state and using it on an event listener. i.e.,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { getDetails } from './actions';

interface Props {
  selecting: boolean;
  getDetails(): Action<void>;
}

@connect((state) => ({
  selecting: state.items.selecting,
}), {
  getDetails,
})
export default class Grid extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
  onMouseEnter = () => {
    if (!this.props.selecting) {
      this.props.getDetails();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} />
    );
  }
}
```

However, whenever the `selecting` property changes, it causes a re-render to my component.

Is there a way to pass a variable from state through `connect` and NOT have it trigger this update to my component? I want it almost as if it were an instance-bound variable rather than a state variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the shouldComponentUpdate() lifecycle function.  This gives you much more granular control over when your component should or shouldn't re-render (at the cost of added code complexity).

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextProps.someLogic !== this.props.someLogic)
        return false; // Don't re-render
    return true;
}
```

Documentation:  [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

> Use shouldComponentUpdate() to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.

Comment: is there a way to hook into the shallow compare of PureComponent? i.e., basically just some logic that says "compare the prevProps and nextProps without the key of 'selected'"